# MVC to MVVM with networking: Architectural appraoch / best practices

Tags: networking, model-view-controller, mvvm, architecture

I have a MVC-based network application which looks similar to this UML-structure:

[UML - Diagram of the current Model-Controller structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpPQC.png)

Currently, the ControllerContainer catches events raised from the network controllers and manipulates the ModelContainer according to the change. The View would access the ModelContainer in case of certain changes (by handling controller events) and display the changed data.

Changing the View-Site to WPF technology brings up the question on how to refactor this structure to a corresponding MVVM - pattern. My first approach in extending the View looks similar to this UML-Diagram:

[UML - diagram of the planned View extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Mxvq.png)

As shown, the ViewModels would consist of several subsets of the current Model. ASFAIK the View <-> ViewModel binding handles the User interaction just fine, but is there any good pratice on how to provide the ViewModels with the network - input (which I already handle in the ControllerContainer)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To partially answer my own question: 
In our current solution, the ViewModels would initialize and simply use the Controllers (or functional interfaces that are imlemented by the Control). Thus, the current MVC structure would stay as it is, the Control - layer representing the functional API of the application and the ViewModel - layer put on top of the Control - layer.

If there is any more elegant solution to merge these patterns, feel free to comment / post answers.